# Default scope Mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, default-scope

I have a big ass collection which uses the same collection which needs to be filter in different ways

```
class PaymentLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MongoMapper::Document

  set_collection_name "logs"

  ...

  # default scope for payment activity
end
```

And for example this.

```
class SuspiciousActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MongoMapper::Document

  set_collection_name "logs"

  ...

  # default scope search for suspicious activity
end
```

Both use the same logs, but each needs a default search on the `type` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoMapper does not support default scope.  As explain on the MongoMapper mailing list when [hamin wanted to discuss how to add default scopes](http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/f4434afb2d8d01b5/4482cf4ee4be7aab)...

> "I personally don't use default scopes. Every time I tried, it ended up biting me." - Brandon Keepers
>
> "I agree with Brandon. I've never had default_scope be useful. It always burns you in the long run. Much better to create a scope/method and always use that method." - John Nunemaker
>
> "I've talked to a few other people and they seem to share your
>   sentiments John and Brandon. I'll file this one away then as
>   unnecessary :)" - Haris Amin

If you *know* that a default scope is the right solution for your problem, you can hack it using MongoMapper's [Single Collection Inheritance module](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/sci.rb#L23) as a model:

```
class PaymentLog
  # ...
  def self.query(options={})
    super.tap { |query| query[:type] = "payment" unless options.key?(:type) }
  end
end
```

Comment: so this overrides the default query method when i do, `paymentLog.all` for example.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech yes, MongoMapper delegates `all` to `query`, so it ends up as `PaymentLog.query.all`...`query` is a decorated `Plucky::Query` https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb#L63-70

Comment: Is it my understanding, that there is no scope at all. Because when I do `Object.first` or `Object.last`, it still brings up the same object.

Comment: But how do I unscoped this?

Answer (score 2):

I find it quite retarded that MongoMapper does not support default scopes, but only because by default it does not sort documents by anything. SQL databases at least have a incremental id which is naturally used. This is the one reason I believe a default scope is very important.